# Sending file from html form to php through javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have created a form in javascript. I don't want to have a submit button on this because it is just one input field. To make it without I just used the onchange function. So my form looks like the following...

```
<form method="post" name="uploadImage">
<input type="file" id="uploadImg" name="uploadImg" onchange="fileClick()" />
</form>
```

Then to account make the form submit I used the js submit function. So my Javascript is the following.

```
function fileClick(){

document.forms["uploadImage"].submit();

$.post(
"uploadImage.php",
{image : $("#uploadImg").val()},
function(data, status){
alert(data);
$("#uploadedImgs").innerHTML = "<img src='" + data + "' alt='uploadedImg' />";
});
}
</script>
```

(and yes I have correctly included JQuery)
But then when I try to submit my data into the php file using this I keep getting it saying $_FILES['image'] is null. My php code is below.

```
<?php
if($_FILES['image']){
echo "Image set";
} else {
echo "No image selected";
}
?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Also if you have a simpler way of doing what I'm trying to do all suggestions are accepted. Thank you all for your help. :D

(final note after post) Yes I am aware that there are also questions very similar to this but most of them are way more advanced than I am with Javascript. This being as simple as it is was very hard and time consuming for me to figure out how to get it to work. So please don't mark as duplicate because I can't understand the other peoples answers. SORRY :(

Comment: @Companjo I would say that's a very similar question. But I'm not very advanced in javascript so I'm trying to keep it simple. Also, after looking over his code I cannot understand it otherwise I would delete this question, considering it a duplicate. Sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

I use ajax for things like this. This code triggers on the file selector value changing. It posts the image value, and alerts the response.

```
$("#uploadImage").change(function(event) {
    var values = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: "uploadImage.php",
        type: "post",
        data: values,
        success: function(response){
            alert(response);
        },
        error:function(){
            //Error
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried plugging this into my code and it didn't seem to work. I might have just done it wrong though. If you wouldn't mind adding me on skype or something so I could talk out how this works, that would be great. If you are willing to do so just reply.